# Authenticated as different user on github through ssh

Tags: security, github, ssh

I seem to have run into some sort of serious security issue on github (? seems like a serious security issue somewhere anyways)

I have a new machine was following Github's instructions to add an ssh key. I generated the ssh key using the steps from [this guide](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), and added it to my account using the steps [here](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

I was getting authentication errors accessing my private repositories, so according to [this help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection) I tried diagnosing my ssh connection with the following command.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Which gives the following output

```
Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I've never even heard of the username it listed. I checked the corresponding page, (github.com/), and it appeared to be a valid github user.

Furthermore, **I am able to push to their repositories through ssh** (I can't do anything with mine either).

It's worth mentioning that I bought this machine used about two weeks ago, but that I'm running a fresh install of Linux (Pop!_OS) on a new drive that I bought a few days ago.

I'm not sure what's going on, but it seems serious and also I'd like to be able to write to my own repositories again.

Comment: Did you try to run ssh in verbose mode to see what key is actually being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that installing some software for Duckiebot put someone else's personal SSH key on my device. Thank you to @juraj for the advice